# Using Ngxtop for monitoring Nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

```
Ngxtop -l file_name
```

takes only 1 log file as its input, Isthere any way by which I can pass 2 log files to ngxtop for monitoring ?
or 
combine two files into 1, so that they both can be monitored ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one file, one way to do it is to use `cat` to first concatenate the files.

Ex: `cat file_new.log >> file_old.log`

and then you can use `ngxtop -l file_old.log`

You can easily scale this method to use any number of files with ngxtop.